# Navigation Menu in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm a newbie with jquery mobile but I want to build a vertical navigation panel with its specific animation (no page changing).

A good example is here ( i don't want sencha touch, i need to do this with jquery mobile): http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/kitchensink/index.html

For example, if you select "User Interface", just the menu is updating (and a button back appear...)
Another good example is IOs, as the dropbox Ipad application (cf http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qeqw5OroHzY)

How I can do that with jquery mobile ? I see panels, the 1.3 new feature, but it's not really the same thing ...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [jQueryUI's .menu](http://jqueryui.com/menu/)

Other than that, it's just a fancy `<aside>`

Comment: hum nothing else ? where's the slide effect ?

Comment: the slide effect is just an animation. I'm sure there are 3rd party plugins that accomplish what you're after. Most stackoverflow questions are Q&A for particular code..